# how to make swig interface file for C++, protobuf

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, swig

Apparently, protobuf need to know all the headers involved.

Below is the content of Header.h

Test.h is the protobuf generated header file

```
#pragma once
#include "Test.h"

class TestClass
{
private:
    test::Person _person;
public:
    bool eventReceiveData(char*);
    bool eventRecieveData(char* const);
    bool eventRecieveData(std::string);
    std::string getData() const;

    void eventReceiveMessage(test::Person);
    test::Person getPerson();
};
```

Since Test.h includes all these header files,

```
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h

#include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
#include <google/protobuf/arenastring.h>
#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/metadata.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>
#include <google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h>
```

does that mean I have to do this?

```
%module Test
%{
#include "Header.h"
%}
%include "Header.h"
%include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
%include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
%include <google/protobuf/arenastring.h>
%include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
%include <google/protobuf/metadata.h>
%include <google/protobuf/message.h>
%include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>
%include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>
%include <google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h>
```

And also, do I have to include all the static libraries for protobuf?

My target language is C#

There is so little information related to using swig and protobuf in the same time.

Comment: I can probably answer the question, but why wouldn't you just serialise it and pass over IPC?

Comment: Sorry on that part I didn't know what I was doing lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that your protobuf object has a namespace I'm assuming you're using the normal C++ protoc.

The short answer to your question is that no, you don't necessary have to include all or any of the protobuf headers inside your SWIG interface. You might want to include some or augment/replace them inside SWIG though, in order to make it actually work completely and neatly. I'll show you how to do it, but I **strongly believe that this is not the right design solution for most cases.** See my suggested alternative at the end of this answer.

As an example for a discussion though I took the person.proto from the protobuf tutorial. I assume that's also what you're working with, but it's hard to say, so here it is:

```
message Person {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

When we run protoc we get one .h file. If we start with a SWIG interface like:

```
%module test
%{
#include "person.pb.h"
%}
%include "person.pb.h"
```

Then we get a mostly unusable C# interface generated - SWIG doesn't wrap `std::string` or Google's `::google::protobuf::int32` types neatly, because it knows nothing about them.

On the other hand if we write a protobuf.i file:

```
%include <std_string.i>
%include <stdint.i>
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION 2006001
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION 2006001
namespace google {
namespace protobuf {
typedef int32 int32_t;
typedef uint8 uint8_t;
// ... whatever else you need
}
}
```

And use that in your module:

```
%module test
%include "protobuf.i"
%{
#include "person.pb.h"
%}
%include "person.pb.h"
```

Then now we're in business, that's the minimum needed to get something sane in a wrapped interface. You'll be able to work with protobuf objects that C++ has created and managed for you from within C++ with "beanlike" behaviour, i.e. basic sets and gets will be usable.

There's plenty of stuff that also won't be usable without more work though, e.g. descriptors, metadata, message types, coded io, strings with ownership transfer.

Each of those is fixable with a bit more work in your SWIG interface however I think you're approaching this problem from the wrong angle. You've got a protobuf compiler for both C# and C++ so what I'd do instead would be to add a `setPerson()` as well as a `getPerson()` method and use in and out typemaps in SWIG to serialise and construct the native C++/C# corresponding types transparently. This is a particularly good plan given that deliberately or otherwise what your `getPerson()` method returns is a copy of the private member not a reference, so changing the underlying protobuf object that's returned won't have any visible effect inside C++ anyway.

Comment: I can probably elaborate on the last part of that question if it's helpful, but I"ll need to get a protobuf compiler for C# working with Mono first.

Comment: I didn't know what I was doing in the 'Wrong angle' part. The problem is much more obvious know!